# Magento 2.3.2 widgets on home page showing twice

Tags: magento2.3, widgets

I am using **magento 2.3.2** with **zemez** theme. I added 8 widgets including slider, featured products and featured brands.

Widgets were showing fine on admin and frontend when checked a month ago. Today when I checked again there weren't any widgets on backend but showing all 8 widgets on frontend. So I imported widgets database tables from a backup and they started showing on backend too.

But the issue I am facing now is that all widgets are showing twice (i.e. 16 widgets) on frontend but on backend 8 widgets.

Seems to be a cache issue. So I Removed **var** folder and ran all commands but issue is still there

Answer (score -1):

Check the database table `cms_block`. It seems that you've created new entries for your widgets.